# Python: Why doesn't this recursion mutate the input list?

Tags: python, list, recursion, mutation

This is a question of understanding Python list mutation. I solved this depth-first search problem and I get correct results. Then I got some feedback for something, that in my opinion shouldn't work, but it works.

Basically, if I use path[0] instead of current_path (by switching the lines in the pairs of commented-out and non-commented lines), the results are the same. I'm trying to understand why this works. I understand that the list within the list path, meaning path[0], is not mutated. However, the list path should be mutated when I assign a different list to the 0th index of path. And yet, it works just fine.

Below is the code, I left the docstring for further clarifications. In the end I pasted the code I played around with to better understand list mutation, but it did not help me. Could somebody explain this?

```
# Problem 3b: Implement get_best_path
def get_best_path(digraph, start, end, path, max_dist_outdoors, best_dist,
                  best_path):
    """
    Finds the shortest path between buildings subject to constraints.
        digraph: Digraph instance
            The graph on which to carry out the search
        start: string, Building number at which to start
        end: string, Building number at which to end
        path: list composed of [[list of strings], int, int]
            Represents the current path of nodes being traversed. Contains
            a list of node names, total distance traveled, and total
            distance outdoors.
        max_dist_outdoors: int
            Maximum distance spent outdoors on a path
        best_dist: int
            The smallest distance between the original start and end node
            for the initial problem that you are trying to solve
        best_path: list of strings
            The shortest path found so far between the original start
            and end node.
    Returns:
        A tuple with the shortest-path from start to end, represented by
        a list of building numbers (in strings), [n_1, n_2, ..., n_k],
        where there exists an edge from n_i to n_(i+1) in digraph,
        for all 1 <= i < k and the distance of that path.

        If there exists no path that satisfies max_total_dist and
        max_dist_outdoors constraints, then return None.
    """
    if not digraph.has_node(Node(start)) or not digraph.has_node(Node(end)):
        raise ValueError('Start or end node, or both not in graph')

    current_path = path[0] + [start]
    path[0]="This line doesn't change a thing, if I use 'current_path', but why?!"
#    path[0] = path[0] + [start]

    if start == end:
        return [current_path, path[1], path[2]]
#        return path

    edges = digraph.get_edges_for_node(Node(start))
    for edge in edges:
        next_node = str(edge.get_destination())

        if next_node not in current_path: #avoiding cycles
#        if next_node not in path[0]: #avoiding cycles

            new_tot = path[1] + edge.get_total_distance()
            new_out = path[2] + edge.get_outdoor_distance()
            if (best_dist==None or best_dist>=new_tot) and new_out<=max_dist_outdoors:

                new_path=get_best_path(digraph, next_node, end, [current_path,new_tot,new_out], \
#                new_path=get_best_path(digraph, next_node, end, [path[0],new_tot,new_out], \
                                                    max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path)

                if new_path != None:
                    best_path = new_path[0]
                    best_dist = new_path[1]
    if best_path == None:
        return None
    return [best_path, best_dist]
```

I played around with the idea here, but as I expected, the input list is mutated. So, why is the list 'path' in the upper case not mutated?

```
def foo_mutating(bar):
    bar[0] = bar[0] + [1]
    print('bar inside foo:', bar)
    if len(bar[0]) == 5:
        return bar
    return foo_mutating(bar)

def foo_nonmut(bar):
    temp_bar0 = bar[0]+[1]
    print('bar inside foo:', bar)
    if len(temp_bar0) == 5:
        return [temp_bar0, bar[1], bar[2]]
    return foo_nonmut([temp_bar0, bar[1], bar[2]])

def test():
    print('-----TESTING NON-MUTATING----')
    bar_init = [[], 22, 33]
    print('bar_init:', bar_init)
    new_bar = foo_nonmut(bar_init)
    print('new_bar:', new_bar)
    print('bar_init:', bar_init)
    print('\n')
    print('-----TESTING MUTATING----')
    bar_init = [[], 22, 33]
    print('bar_init:', bar_init)
    new_bar = foo_mutating(bar_init)
    print('new_bar:', new_bar)
    print('bar_init:', bar_init)

test()
```

prints:

```
-----TESTING NON-MUTATING----
bar_init: [[], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
new_bar: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
bar_init: [[], 22, 33]

-----TESTING MUTATING----
bar_init: [[], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
bar inside foo: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
new_bar: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
bar_init: [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 22, 33]
```

Comment: Any chance you can provide a more "minimal" [mcve]? I'm sure there is a shorter code that reproduces the behavior you notice.

Comment: @DeepSpace , I just spent 30min trying to reduce the problem and I ended up with something else, I don't think I'm able to recreate this scenario. I've only been learning programming for 2-3 months now, so the deeper meaning of syntax, operators and objects is still kind of blurry, so it's hard for me to reproduce something I don't fully understand. But this is something I will definitely keep in my mind for any future questions. Thank you for the feedback on the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why doesn't this recursion mutate the input list?

Because it is not *called with* the input list, and thus does not have it available to mutate.

When you make the recursive call (I reformatted a bit):

```
# "non-mutating" approach, as in the original code
new_path = get_best_path(
    digraph, next_node, end, [current_path,new_tot,new_out],
    max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path
)

# "mutating" approach, using the commented-out line
new_path=get_best_path(
    digraph, next_node, end, [path[0],new_tot,new_out],
    max_dist_outdoors, best_dist, best_path
)
```

The attempt at the algorithm mutating the path, creates a new list that is passed to the recursive call, so it does not mutate. Contrast with the toy example:

```
# "non-mutating" recursive call
return foo_nonmut([temp_bar0, bar[1], bar[2]])

# "mutating" recursive call
return foo_mutating(bar)
# Notice, it does not make a new list.
```

In general, recursive algorithms are much easier to reason about when you don't rely on mutation. You'll probably also find you get cleaner, easier-to-understand code by using some kind of class to represent the paths. Then you can give that class non-mutating methods for "create a new path with the specified node appended to the node name list" and "create a new path with modified distance data". (or better yet - both at once, giving it the Edge instance from which it gets all the necessary data).

Something like:

```
class Path:
    def __init__(self, names, distance, outdoor):
        self._names, self._distance, self._outdoor = names, distance, outdoor

    def __contains__(self, node):
        return node in self._names

    def with_edge(self, edge):
        return Path(
            # incidentally, you should be using `property`s instead of methods
            # for this Edge data.
            self._names + [edge.get_destination()],
            self._distance + edge.get_total_distance(),
            self._outdoor + edge.get_outdoor_distance()
        )

    def better_than(self, other, outdoor_limit):
        if self._outdoor <= outdoor_limit:
            return False
        best_distance = other._distance
        return best_distance is None or best_distance >= self._distance

    def end(self): # where we start recursing from during pathfinding.
        return self._names[-1]
```

Now we can do something more like:

```
# instead of remembering best_path and best_dist separately, we'll just
# use a Path object for best_path, and we can ignore the outdoor distance
# when interpreting the results outside the recursion.
edges = digraph.get_edges_for_node(Node(start))
for edge in edges:
    if edge.get_destination() in path:
        continue
    candidate = path.with_edge(edge)
    if candidate.better_than(best_path, max_dist_outdoors):
        # We can remove some parameters from the recursive call,
        # because we can infer them from the passed-in `path`.
        new_path = get_best_path(digraph, end, path, max_dist_outdoors, best_path)
        if new_path is not None:
            best_path = new_path
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanations! I'll implement such a class, seems like a good idea and practice! But now I see that I haven't quite asked the right question, so I'm only getting half the picture... Here is the other half:
We have a 2-branch tree, starting at 1: `1-2-4` and `1-3-5`; I need to get from 1 to 5 using the path[0] case; I'm now at 2 and the code says: index 0 of list 'path' points to this new list [1,2]+[4]; It's a dead end, I go up a level. How is index 0 of 'path' pointing back to [1], since the previous assignment in the latest rec. call tells it to point to [1,2,4]?